# About String split for two numbered variable which is read as String

Tags: java

if I read `1symbol2` as a String i can split that using `String.split("")` into 3 variables but if I read `12 symbol 16` as a string and if I apply `String.split(" ")` it is split into 6 variables. How can I split that into 3 variables that are (12, symbol,16)?
**Note:** 
The following any of them can be considered as Symbols +,-,*,/,%,~,!,@,#,$,^,&

Comment: Use String.split('+'), it will give you (12,16)

Comment: If you apply `split(" ")` to "12+16" you get an array of length **one**, not six as you say.

Comment: I think you mean `string.split("")`. Anyways, here is the regex that you can use `(?<=[^\d])|(?=[^\d])`

Answer (score 1):

If you can separate the three string 12 + and 16 with a comma, means something like --> 12,+,16 then below code will work for you.

```
String str = "12,+,16";
String a[] = str.split(",");
System.out.println(a[0]+" "+a[1]+" "+a[2]);

Result will be --> 12 + 16
```

Try this and let me know

Comment: Thank you so much it worked.

Comment: @teja mandadapu : Great, Enjoy 

Answer (score 1):

You can use following `regex` to separate your string in parts:

```
String myString = "12+16";
String[] result = myString.split("(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Output:

> [12,+,16]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `String.split(" ")`, you can just do:       `String.split("+")`